# How to calculate overall reference coverage with MUMmer?

Tags: assembly, coverage

Is the MUMmer suite capable of calculating reference sequence coverage statistics for all query sequences collectively? It would be possible to achieve by parsing the output of `nucmer` / `show-coords` / `show-tiling` but it seems like there should be a better way. I currently do this using a sensitive read mapper, `samtools depth` and some scripting.

To clarify, I'd like to know the reference coverage achieved using all of the query sequences (i.e. the whole *de novo* assembly, in my case).

Comment: Would QUAST work on your data? It runs MUMmer and reports coverage.

Comment: Good suggestion @user172818. I'll investigate.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I believe all you need to do is to run `dnadiff` from MUMmer. That will run a comparison and output a number of useful metrics.

Comment: Many thanks Devon. The `QRY` field of the `AlignedBases` record in `dnadiff`'s out.report seems to be what I was after. Although clearly a powerful tool, I was surprised how slow dnadiff was to run.